# Pandas update column value based on values of groupby having multiple if else

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, group-by

I have a pandas data frame, where 3 columns X, Y, and Z are used for grouping. I want to update column B (or store it in a separate column) for each group based on the conditions shown in the code. But all I'm getting is nulls as the final outcome.
I'm not sure what am I doing incorrectly

Below is the sample of the table (I have not taken all the cases, but I'm including them in the code):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kROj.png)

```
group=df.groupby(['X','Y','Z'])
for a,b in group:
    if ((b.colA==2).all()):
        df['colB']=b.colB.max() 
    elif (((b.colA>2).all()) and (b.colB.max() >=2)):
        df['colB']=b.colB.max()
   elif (((b.ColC.str.isdigit()).all()) and ((b.ColC.str.len()==2).all())):
        df['colB']=b.ColC.str[0].max()
   elif (((b.ColC.str.isdigit()).all()) and ((b.ColC.str.len()>2).all())):
        df['ColB']=b.ColC.str[:-2].max()
   elif ((b.ColC.str[0].str.isdigit().all()) and (b.ColC.str.contains('[A-Z]').all()) and 
          (b.ColC.str[-1].str.isalpha().all())):
        df['colB']=b.ColC.str[:-1].astype(float).max()
   elif (b.ColC.str[0].str.isalpha().all() and b.ColC.str.contains('[0-9]').all()):
        df['ColB']=len(set(" ".join(re.findall("[A-Z]+", str(b.ColC)))))
    else:
        df['colB']=np.nan
```

Comment: Your code is slightly confusing as don't understand what your goal is independent from the code. If you only wish to update `colB` based on some condition, using `.loc[]` is probably a better choice. I don't see what you need `groupby()` for in your example. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I have to update column B based on different group values for the column. I think looking at the table ( In the link) will help you understand, why I need groupby`

Comment: I understand that you want to update `colB` differently for certain subsets of your data, but you can achieve this with df.loc[filter, colB] = 'Some Value'. `groupby()` is intended to perform some operation with the group (`a` in your loop) which you are not even using.

Comment: For example if I see the first condition, different groups have value in col A as 2. But the maximum value of colB for those groups are different. In table A, for first group it is 3 and last group it is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main flaw in your code is that you set some value in
the **whole** *colB* column, whereas it should be set
only in rows from the current group.

To do your task the right way, define a function to be applied to
each group:

```
def myFun(b):
    if (b.colA == 2).all():
        rv = b.colB.max()
    elif (b.colA > 2).all() and (b.colB.max() >= 2):
        rv = b.colB.max()
    elif (b.colC.str.isdigit()).all() and (b.colC.str.len() == 2).all():
        rv = b.colC.str[0].max()
    elif b.colC.str.isdigit().all() and (b.colC.str.len() > 2).all():
        rv = b.colC.str[:-2].max()
    elif b.colC.str[0].str.isdigit().all() and b.colC.str[-1].str.isalpha().all():
        rv = b.colC.str[:-1].astype(int).max()
    elif b.colC.str[1].str.isalpha().all() and b.colC.str.contains('[0-9]').all():
        rv = len(set("".join(b.colC.str.extract("([A-Z]+)")[0])))
    else:
        rv = np.nan
    return pd.Series(rv, index=b.index)
```

Another flaw is in your data. The last group *('J', 'K', 'L')* will
be processed by the first *if* path.
In order to be processed by the fifth path, I put *0* in *colA*
in this group, so that the source DataFrame contains:

```
   X  Y  Z  colA  colB colC
0  A  B  C     2     3  NaN
1  A  B  C     2     1  NaN
2  D  E  F     3     4  NaN
3  D  E  F     3     1  NaN
4  D  E  F     3     2  NaN
5  G  H  I     3     0   35
6  G  H  I     3     0   63
7  G  H  I     3     0   78
8  J  K  L     0     0   2H
9  J  K  L     0     0   5B
```

And to fill the result column, run:

```
df['Result'] = df.groupby(['X','Y','Z'], group_keys=False).apply(myFun)
```

The result is:

```
   X  Y  Z  colA  colB colC Result
0  A  B  C     2     3  NaN      3
1  A  B  C     2     1  NaN      3
2  D  E  F     3     4  NaN      4
3  D  E  F     3     1  NaN      4
4  D  E  F     3     2  NaN      4
5  G  H  I     3     0   35      7
6  G  H  I     3     0   63      7
7  G  H  I     3     0   78      7
8  J  K  L     0     0   2H      5
9  J  K  L     0     0   5B      5
```

Or, to place the result in *colB*, change the output column
name in the above code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the function will start after I write      ```group=df.groupby(['X','Y','Z'])
    for a,b in group:                                                                                                                               
   def myFun(b)                                                                                                                     
```

Comment: This function is applied to each group. Run my code **instead** of your code (*group = ...* and the following loop).